# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process with specific dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, gram-schmidt

I have three vectors $$v_1=(1,1,1)^T$$ $$v_2=(1,1,0)^T$$ $$v_3=(1,0,0)^T$$ and special dot product definition
$$(\overline{(x_1,x_2,x_3)},\overline{(y_1,y_2,y_3)})=2x_1y_2+x_1y_1+2x_2y_1+x_3y_3$$
I use standard Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. So $$e_1=v_1=(1,1,1)^T$$ $$e_2 = v_2 - \frac{(v_2, e_1)}{(e_1, e_1)} \cdot e_1 = (1,1,-5)^T$$ and $$e_3 = v_3 - \frac{(v_3,e_1)}{(e_1,e_1)}\cdot e_1 - \frac{(v_3,e_2)}{(e_2,e_2)} \cdot e_2 = (2,-3,0)^T$$ But $(e_2, e_3) = -9$ instead of $0$. I can't recognize my mistake. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The "dot product" isn't symmmetric

Comment: @user251257 Sorry, my mistake, I fixed it. But it changes nothing.

Comment: Your dot product is not positive definite: $\langle (0,1,0),(0,1,0)\rangle = 2(0)(1) + (0)(0) + 2(1)(0) + (0)(0) = 0$, but $(0,1,0)\neq (0,1,0)$. Also, it's not positive semidefinite: $\langle (1,-1,0), (1,-1,0)\rangle = 2(1)(-1) + (1)(1) + 2(-1)(1) = -3\lt 0$.

Comment: It isn't positive definite. So the gs-process may fail.

Comment: Also, your calculations are wrong. $\langle v_2,e_1\rangle = \langle (1,1,0),(1,1,1)\rangle = 2+1+2 =5$; $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle = \langle (1,1,1),(1,1,1) \rangle= 2+1+2+1=6$. So $e_2 = (1,1,0) - \frac{5}{6}(1,1,1)$, and somehow I doubt that is equal to $(1,1,-5)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $e_2 = (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6},\frac{-5}{6})$ but I multiplied it by six, it doesn't make sense

Comment: You wrote that $e_2$ is **equal** to $(1,1,-5)$. If you meant "proportional", then don't use the equal sign!

Comment: Note 1: Don't use $=$ when you mean "and after I multiply by a constant, then I get"; the symbol `=` means **equal**, not "and then you do some other stuff and you get this". 
Note 2: Gram-Schmidt with a product that is not definite can fail, because your denominators can be zero. In this case that doesn't happen, but you seem to have miscalculated the last inner product:
$\langle (2,-3,0),(1,1,-5)\rangle = 2(2)(1) + (2)(1) + 2(-3)(1) + (0)(-5) = 4+2-6 = 0$. Why do you say it is $-9$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you a lot, that was the mistake